# insert bootstrap popover on amazon.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, bootstrap-4

I am writing a simple chrome extension and I want to use my content.js script to insert a simple bootstrap popover on an amazon.com product page.

I do the following in **content.js** to insert scripts for the popover and toggle it.  I know this code is functional because the the html and jquery creates a working popover when I run it in a popup window I create with the extension:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var title = document.getElementById('productTitle');
 htmlToInsert = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> <script src="Popper.js"></script> <script src="bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>'
title.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', htmlToInsert);
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
})
```

This gives me 'Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's tooltips require Popper.js' or '$(popper) is not a function'.  I've been looking around and seen suggestions that the error might be related to multiple versions of jquery in the namespace of the page (amazon) and that I should use no conflict version of jquery but that didnt work.  I also tried playing with the order of the imports but that didnt fix it. 
The files referenced are local copies of the bootstrap code.
Thanks!

Comment: well popper.js is a library bootstrap relies on to show the tooltips and some other stuff. have you tried adding it to your code ?

Comment: I think so---thats why I have <script src="Popper.js"> in the htmlToInsert variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you inject scripts into a page, the src URL should be related to your extension path. 
but in your way, it's actually related to Amazon webpage path, that's why it's not working.

Do this in your `manifest.json`, `content_scripts` part (I shorten the file name for simple, change them to your actually file name):

```
"content_scripts":[{
"js":["jquery.js","Popper.js", "bootstrap.js", "content.js"],
"css":["bootstrap.css"]
}]
```

then you can just do this in your `content.js`:

```js
$("body").append(`<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>`)

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```